# Is it possible to Feature Detect Click to Call in Android and iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I'm working on a website that has a requirement of a "Call Now" button that is a Click to Call link.  This works fine on phones that can make phone calls; however, looks and acts odd from a usability point of view on devices that cannot make phone calls (e.g. tablets).

Is there a way to use JavaScript and detect if the device supports making phone calls?

Answer (score 2):

After some reading, I think the best method as of now, is to look for the following conditions in the user-agent string.

```
if ((string.Contains("mobile") && string.Contains("android")) {
   // device is an android phone.
}
else if (string.Contains("android")) {
   // device is likely and android tablet
}
else if (string.Contains("ipad")) {
   // device is an iPad
}
else if (string.Contains("iphone")) {
   // device is an iPhone.
}
```

It's not perfect, but it may be your best bet.